# Is --cmake-force-configure a cmake option?

Tags: cmake

In a build script I have, I found `--cmake-force-configure` being passed as option to CMake. I don't find documentation for that, only on [ROS forums](https://answers.ros.org/question/333534/when-to-use-cmake-cleanconfigure/) as option for colcon. Is `--cmake-force-configure` a valid option for CMake?? If not, how to emulate what it is supposed to do (force CMake to execute the configure step)

Comment: "force CMake to execute the configure step" - Running `cmake -S <source_dir> -B <build_dir>` will execute configure step even if configuration has already been performed before. If you want to perform clean configuration (without cached values), then just erase build directory or remove `CMakeCache.txt` file from it.

Comment: For a dir `build_dir` that contains a cmake project that was already configured, you can simply do `cmake build_dir` which repeats the configuration with the options cached in `build_dir/CMakeCache.txt`. Adding cache entries can be done via `-D` option and updating an existing cache entry can be done combining the options `-U` and `-D`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is --cmake-force-configure a cmake option?

No.

> Is --cmake-force-configure a valid option for CMake?

No.

> If not, how to emulate what it is supposed to do (force CMake to execute the configure step)

Run `cmake` configure step again.

The thread you found starts with `What is the use of the following arguments to ****colcon build****?`. It is an option for `colcon build`.